# See activity log in Gitlab Issues

Tags: gitlab

Is there a way in (standard, hosted) Gitlab to see a chronology of my activity? At times it would be useful for timesheeting to be able to see what issues I have worked on during the day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, according to the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/#user-activity) it's possible to view the most recent activity on [a user profile page](https://gitlab.com/users/gitlab-bot/activity).

[image]

Comment: Ah, seems obvious now. I didn't see the row of tabs up the top.